# How do I convert wireshark capture files to text files?

Tags: command-line-interface, wireshark

How can I convert wirshark captures (.cap) files to text files or some format from which I can read the file and parse its contents ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Open up Wireshark, select your .cap file, and then go to File->Export and choose the options that you want.

So, if you need to do it from the command line, use tshark.exe, as follows.

```
>tshark -i - < "c:\filename.cap" > "c:\output.txt
```

> If you want to write the decoded form of packets to a file, run TShark without the -w option, and redirect its standard output to the file (do not use the -w option).

Comment: File->Save As also has numerous formats.

Comment: @David - none of those are human-readable, they're all meant for use with other traffic analyzers. "Export" is the one that gets you friendly text files, or structured things like PS, CSV, etc.

Comment: am sorry I forgot to mention . I want to convert it using some command line ?

Comment: OK, edited my answer to include command-line options. @Davey, below, also posted a good answer using an additional tool you may or may not have, tcpdump.

Answer (score 11):

The -A option of `tcpdump` prints each packet in human readable ASCII and happily deals with wireshark files and you can do it all from the command line:

```
tcpdump -A -r stackoverflow.cap > stackoverflow.txt
```

The output looks like:

```
9:22:33.664874 IP 192.168.1.11.33874 > stackoverflow.com.www: Flags [P.], seq 1117095075:1117095829, ack 3371415182, win 9648, options [nop,nop,TS val 9533909 ecr 313735664], length 754
E..&..@.@../....E;...R.PB.........%........
..y...9.GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: serverfault.com
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.375.70 Safari/533.4
Accept: application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: __qca=P0-141773580-1259521886021; __utmz=81883924.1275328201.133.5.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=hudson%20build%20dir; usr=t=kXSBoIG5Jk6S&s=wGmaIuhAD0eH; __utma=81883924.2034104685.1272993451.1276186265.1276193655.189; __utmc=81883924; __utmb=81883924.6.10.1276193655
If-Modified-Since: Thu, 10 Jun 2010 10:17:12 GMT
```

Comment: Assuming he's running on Unix. Or running WinDump or other Windows clone of TCPDump. Since the guy mentioned Wireshark, I limited my answer to the tools included in the Wireshark package.

Answer (score 3):

I use the `tshark -x -r file.pcap` command line when hexdump like output is good for post processing.

Answer (score 2):

tshark -x -r "c:\result.pcap" > "c:\final.txt"

That's it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you able to open wireshark and open that .cap file, then export it from the file menu as a text file? Trying to remember off the top of my head but I thought you could...

Comment: am sorry I forgot to mention . I want to convert it using some command line ?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say exact type of text format, so just wanted to mention other solutions I came across, while looking up this topic:

```
tshark -V -r file_to_convert.pcap
```

or

```
tshark -F k12text -r file_to_convert.pcap
```

found from

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68410188/how-to-save-pcap-file-to-text-file-using-tshark

https://codeghar.wordpress.com/2009/07/21/convert-pcap-file-to-text/#comments

For me personally, I don't think I always want a hexdump when I want text.